# General error: 1553

Tags: mysql, database, symfony

On my local project, following the command `composer install` and `sf do:sc:up --dump-sql`, then do `sf do:sc:up --force` and I have this error:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]
An exception occurred while executing 'DROP INDEX IDX_123456789 ON fos_user':
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1553 Cannot drop index 'IDX_123456789': needed in a foreign key constraint

[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1553 Cannot drop index 'IDX_123456789': needed in a foreign key constraint

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1553 Cannot drop index 'IDX_123456789': needed in a foreign key constraint
```

I understand that a key is missing but I do not know what to do...
I try to do it from the command line

Thank you :)

Comment: Read the error message carefully.  The command you ran tried to drop an index which is being used in a foreign key constraint.  You can try removing the constraint first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a common problem during the development stage of a Symfony application. Especially when you are working on/experimenting with associations between entities. If this occurs, the fastest way to get back up and running again is to purge and rebuild your development database. To do so, run this from your application folder:

```
php app/console doctrine:database:drop --force
php app/console doctrine:database:create
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Optionally, load your fixtures back into the database (if you have them)

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load -n
```

This should give you a fresh instance of your database following the latest mapping rules.